# What are the plans to support wireframes after flash player is no longer available?

Tags: bug

I am fairly new to using this site and have not used the wireframe tool before, although I do have the desktop version of Balsamiq.

I thought I would give it a whirl but was told I need flash player installed. However, Chrome kicks up a fuss and I need to allow Flash Player for individual sites. This is ok, except Chrome is also telling me that after December 2020 it will no longer support Flash Player at all. [Here is a brief bit of information](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/adobe-flash-end-of-support#:%7E:text=Adobe%20will%20end%20support%20of,will%20be%20disabled%20by%20default.&text=Flash%20will%20be%20completely%20removed,%2C%202020%2C%20via%20Windows%20Update.), plenty more available if you search for it.

As of 2021, Flash is completely unsupported in any modern browser

[image: Requires Flash]

So, any plans in the pipeline to still support wireframes in posts?

---

And if so, how will existing wireframes be affected if at all?

As per comments, historic posts shouldn't suffer as PNG files are used for displaying posts anyway.

Comment: The existing wireframes are included in questions as `.png` images to StackOverflow's provisioned `i.stack.imgur.com` hosting, so they'll remain intact. I would guess that the "download bmml source" links that appear below would remain functional as well, but I'm not sure. It'd be nice to hear if there was any other information on this. I'm sure most of us do not own wireframing software, so it'd certainly be useful for us all to have a common in-site tool.

Comment: @maxathousand: Ah yes, that makes sense to store both the original wireframe data and a PNG render of it. Much faster for page loading, and solves the issue I refer to about historic posts. Still leaves the question of supporting the feature going forward though. I think I read that Balsamiq actually have HTML 5 only (non-flash) support in their own cloud services, so it might be a case that UX just needs to get in contact and work out how to transition over (if at all possible).

Comment: Since [my bug report regarding this issue](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3406/42368) has been closed as a duplicate of this question, I've taken the liberty of adding the [tag:bug] tag to this question.

Comment: Three **years** later, why is that _button_ still there in the interface? It's not usable by anyone. Is it just sitting there hoping someone will gift an HTML5 implementation to replace the Flash? (IMHO, it should be not only removed, but replaced with the snippets button found on other Stack sites. Not everyone can illustrate their UX questions/answers with a JS+CSS+HTML demo, but the number of users who _can_ is greater than 0.)