# UI Wireframe editor requires Flash, which is dead

Tags: bug, design, mockups

There is already a discussion question about this:

- [What are the plans to support wireframes after flash player is no longer available?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3370/42368)

but since [Flash is end-of-life](https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html) and no major browser supports running Flash content any more, I'd like to raise the severity of this from [discussion](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) to [bug](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug).

At the very least, the defunct button in the toolbar should be removed, until a more permanent solution can be found:

[image: screenshot of the toolbar with a free-hand circle around the wireframe button]

Comment: Agreed. And this icon doesn't communicate well - it seems like a table designer.